# Inconsistent use of "close question" and "community wiki"?

Tags: discussion, community-wiki, close-reasons

Would you say that the following two Erlang questions can be cited as good examples of how SO's closing policies are intended to work?

- [Why did you decide "against" using Erlang?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2199368/why-did-you-decide-against-using-erlang) (community wiki)
- [Where is Erlang used and why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1636455/where-is-erlang-used-and-why) (closed)

I would argue that, at first glance, both questions are open-ended and solicit discussion. However, the first one asks for *specific* examples and has a well-defined scope, while the second one invites general comments about Erlang usage without restrictions.

On the other hand, they might be perceived as opposite questions, in which case the handling would be inconsistent.

Comment: Community wiki questions are an obsolete feature, for the most part. Please read [
The Future of Community Wiki](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/the-future-of-community-wiki/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are right, both questions aren't really suitable for Stack Overflow, in fact the [Why did you decide "against" using Erlang?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2199368/why-did-you-decide-against-using-erlang) questions was [closed the day it was asked](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/2199368/revisions) and then re-opened. I imagine what contributed to it being re-opened was that it was turned to Community Wiki, a practice that we've since abandoned, [Community Wiki is not a "get out of jail, free" card](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/the-future-of-community-wiki/).

As Mad Scientist [already mentioned](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/143276/162704), it will probably be closed again now that you've brought attention to it, as it is it's [a broken window](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Broken_windows_theory) and it would be absolutely pointless for it to stay open, there would be no benefit of additional answers.

Answer (score 6):

Both are old questions, they are not representative of the current policies of the site. Whether such old questions get closed depends on users flagging them for moderator attention. I'd guess that the first question will be closed shortly after you drew attention to it by this meta post.